# Separate error warn from each file uploaded html php

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

Sorry for the messy code, I'm just a newbie.

How can I separate the error of each file uploaded so that I can make different html code?

```
switch ( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] ) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        $photo_errors0[0] = 'No file sent';
        $photo_errors1[1] = 'No file sent';
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        $photo_errors0[0] = 'Max file size exceeded!';
        $photo_errors1[1] = 'Max file size exceeded!';
        break;
    default:
        $photo_errors0[0] = 'Unknown errors';
        $photo_errors1[1] = 'Unknown errors';
        break;
}

<?php foreach ($photo_errors0 as $photo_error0):?>
    <div class="photo-error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $photo_error0 ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($photo_errors1 as $photo_error1):?>
    <div class="photo-error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $photo_error1 ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What is your current result?  What is your expected result?  Are you getting errors or just not the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

before my code is, this is work but if 2 files error the errors show at once, i'm trying to separate the error from the each file so can make easyli on html.
thx

```
switch ( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] ) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'No file sent';
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'Max file size exceeded!';
                    break;
                default:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'Unknown errors';
                    break;

<?php foreach ($photo_errors as $photo_error):?>
<div class="photo-error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $photo_error ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```